# Google Cloud Endpoints, Objectify and Persistence

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I've follow this tuto for my project (https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial), and everything works fine.

But when I wanted to use with objectify classes for my entities, It doesn't work, i can't retrieve data on my datastore with my android app !

For example, with that code it's okay, I can get my user back from my android app:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Index;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Index
public class Utilisateur {

    //Nos variables de classes
    @Id String num_portable; //Clé pour notre entité NOTION CLE PRIMAIRE String car c'est à nous de le définir.
    Boolean sexe;
    int date_naissance;
    String position_geo;
    String liste_contact;
    Boolean blacklistage;

    //Constructeur par défaut (Obligatoire pour Objectify)
    private Utilisateur(){}

    public Utilisateur (String num_portable, Boolean sexe, int date_naissance, String position_geo, String liste_contact, Boolean blacklistage) {

        this.num_portable=num_portable;
        this.sexe=sexe;
        this.date_naissance=date_naissance;
        this.position_geo=position_geo;
        this.liste_contact=liste_contact;
        this.blacklistage=blacklistage;                
    }

    public String getNum_portable() {
        return num_portable;
    }



}
```

But I don't use Objectify.. When I want to use Objectify, with that code, it doesn't works :
I'm just replace this code :

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Index;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
```

With this one :

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;
```

and I get this error on my app engine:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: Class Utilisateur for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class Utilisateur for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
```

So my question is: Can we use Objectify with Android App or the data persistence doesnt work with it (And App Engine)?

**Edit:** That is my code on my android app that call backend(Same code as here => https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial):

```
public class JeveuxvoirActivity extends Activity {


      private ListView utilisateursList;
      private List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs = null;

    //Création de notre activité
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            //Création de notre interface graphique
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Remove title bar
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            //On définit le Layout de notre activité
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_jeveuxvoir);

            utilisateursList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_principal_user);

            // start retrieving the list of nearby places
            new ListOfUtilisateursAsyncRetriever().execute();



        }    


        //*******************************************************
        //                  FONCTIONS ASYNC
        //*******************************************************
      /**
       * AsyncTask for retrieving the list of places (e.g., stores) and updating the
       * corresponding results list.
       */
      private class ListOfUtilisateursAsyncRetriever extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CollectionResponseUtilisateur> {

        @Override
        protected CollectionResponseUtilisateur doInBackground(Void... params) {


          Utilisateurendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Utilisateurendpoint.Builder(
              AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);

          endpointBuilder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder);


          CollectionResponseUtilisateur result;

          Utilisateurendpoint endpoint = endpointBuilder.build();

          try {
            result = endpoint.listUtilisateur().execute();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
          }
          return result;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        protected void onPostExecute(CollectionResponseUtilisateur result) {
          ListAdapter utilisateursListAdapter = createUtilisateurListAdapter(result.getItems());
          utilisateursList.setAdapter(utilisateursListAdapter);

          utilisateurs = result.getItems();
        }
      }

        private ListAdapter createUtilisateurListAdapter(List<Utilisateur> utilisateurs) {

            List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            for (Utilisateur utilisateur : utilisateurs) {
              Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              map.put("utilisateurIcon", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
              map.put("utilisateurPort", utilisateur.getNumPortable());
              data.add(map);
            }

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JeveuxvoirActivity.this, data, R.layout.utilisateur_item,
                new String[] {"utilisateurIcon", "utilisateurPort"},
                new int[] {R.id.utilisateur_Icon, R.id.utilisateur_port});

            return adapter;
          }
```

Comment: Hi, Objectify is designed for AppEngine Datastore so it should works regardless how you access your endpoints (Android, webapp, etc.). Can you provide the code snippet where you make the objectify query?

Comment: Also, just to be sure, have you registered your class `Utilisateur` through Objectify? See https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Registering_Entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA and objectify are 2 alternatives for connecting to dataStore. Avoid using both together. Both have their own conventions that work best if used alone.

Comment: Thanks ! But I switch on Objectify, which manage better parent/child relationship than JDO or JPA :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd recommend too. Though it takes getting used to. Make sure you go through the short and sweet docs. And use the latest version, there are breaking changes done all the time.